# JAVA SimpleDateFormat returns wrong format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I need to convert a simple String eg:

30.06.2017 18:00

to a Date, but the simpledateformat i set just wont apply. for some reason it gives output like this

Fri Jun 30 18:00:00 UTC 2017

I know there are other questions concerning this issue , but I think iam certain that i followed all the instructions correctly,
I set the format correct and the strange thing is , I used the same code in another place and it works fine.
I tried using the locale.ENGLISH part and the "strict" attribute.. 
really seems like netbeans is trolling me

THANK U SO MUCH

```
          System.out.println(newtoday);
```

gives

```
          "30.06.2017 18:00";
```

then I try to format it:

```
          try {
              thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").parse(newtoday);
                            System.out.println(thedate);
          } catch (ParseException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(frame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
```

Output is

```
          Fri Jun 30 18:00:00 UTC 2017
```

---

Thank u dpr for ur answer but the problem is not the "output"

what im doing is :

collect a timeseries for jfreechart:

i have a list of dates to parse and add which works fine

```
        Date thedate=null;
          try {
              thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time);
          } catch (ParseException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(frame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }ts1.add(new Millisecond(thedate), ap);
```

,
but the last element of the timesieries has a different format, thats why i have to format it, which works to get a string in the right format (newtoday)

now after i format the date i use again

```
       ts1.add(new Millisecond(thedate), apt);
```

but it doesnt add to the series

now i thought the problem is the dateformat taht isnt recognized by the addtotimeseries ,

if u say its not the format.. do u see another error?

cheers

Comment: I think you need to add more context to your code snippets. At least I'm not able to tell what you're doing or even what you're doing wrong, from the information you provided.

Comment: And I think you should post a second question for your actual problem as this one has already been close as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You output the date using

```
System.out.println(thedate);
```

This doesn't use the date format you used to parse the date, but uses the `toString()` method of `java.util.Date`. This is why you see the date being print in a different format than expected.

To use you date format for parsing and output do something like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
Date thedate = dateFormat.parse(newtoday);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(thedate));
```